# Orchard Permissions in a custom module

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions, orchardcms

So I've created my first Orchard module, which is essentially just a CRUD in the admin panel, with a front-end form available to the public. Now I need to give different levels of access to different user roles in the admin panel. I've created the "admin" users fine, but now I have trouble with the less privlidged users, who can only see a subset of the records.

The problem is I have NO IDEA where to start. I would be happy to just say on my List screen: `if (UserRole == "SomeRestrictedRole") Select.Where("however we restrict");` - but I don't know how to access the UserRole (I'm also fairly new to .NET MVC).

I think the PROPER solution would be to extend IPermissions or something like that? But again, I can't find any tutorials or docs to point me in the right direction.

Here are the docs I have read so far:

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-a-module-with-a-simple-text-editor

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-data-access

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Managing-users-and-roles

http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-permissions

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right, don't restrict access based on roles, but rather on permissions. Look at any Permissions.cs for examples of implementation. Then search for the permissions declared in there to see examples of enforcing them. It's really easy, you'll see :)

Comment: Thanks, I was using the binary version of Orchard. Loaded up the source and you're right, it was quite obvious to copy an existing Permissions.cs then use Authorizer.Authorize